# Object mutates in Redux despite Object.assign and Spread syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I have a generator function in a Redux Saga that gets an ID, gets the state and dispatches a an action with the state without the object key with the matching id in it. The object in the reducer it should've replaced not mutated looks like this:

```js
{
    [CURRENT YEAR]: {
      [DAY OF YEAR]: {
        [ID THAT SHOULD BE DELETED]: {}
      },
    },
};
```

When this function ran using the commented out delete operator it would mutate the entire state in redux and in ALL Redux loggers (prev and after change) and my selectors would return the previous memoized version because no change was detected. I solved this by creating a new object with lodash Omit, but is there any faster or < 21kb solution to this?

```js
function* removeExerciseAsync(action: any) {
  const { currentDate, currentYear }: DateState = yield select((state: AppState) => state.date);
  const years = yield select(selectYears);

  const dayOfYear = currentDate.dayOfYear();


  const newYearState: DaySummaryTypes = Object.assign({}, years[currentYear]);

  const exerciseId = action.payload;

  if (!newYearState[dayOfYear][exerciseId]) return;

  // delete newYearState[dayOfYear][exerciseId];

  const newState = omit(newYearState, `${dayOfYear}.${exerciseId}`);

  yield put(updateYearExercises({ [currentYear]: newState }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` does a shallow copy of the object, means the object on the top level is different but the nested objects still reference the previous objects. Here you're making change to the nested object that has the same reference as the object sitting in your redux store, hence mutating the redux state. You can try copying the nested object also like this:

```
function* removeExerciseAsync(action: any) {
  const { currentDate, currentYear }: DateState = yield select((state: AppState) => state.date);
  const years = yield select(selectYears);

  const dayOfYear = currentDate.dayOfYear();


  const newYearState: DaySummaryTypes = {
    ...years[currentYear],
    [dayOfYear]: {
      ...years[currentYear][dayOfYear]
    }
  };

  const exerciseId = action.payload;

  if (!newYearState[dayOfYear][exerciseId]) return;

  delete newYearState[dayOfYear][exerciseId];

  // const newState = omit(newYearState, `${dayOfYear}.${exerciseId}`);

  yield put(updateYearExercises({ [currentYear]: newState }));
}
```